# Replace a string with sed script

Tags: sed

Input:

```
Proc Natl Acad Sci U S A. 2014 May 27;111(21):7819-24. doi: 10.1073/pnas.1400586111. Epub 2014 May 13.
```

Desired output:

```
Proc Natl Acad Sci U S A. 2014 May 27;111(21):7819-24.
```

What I tried:

```
sed 's/doi: *//'
```

Comment: Good question. Short, but says it all, including what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
sed 's/doi: .*//'
```

In the pattern you tried, the `*` applies to the space before it, so `doi:` followed by an arbitrary number of spaces is removed, and what comes after that remains.

`.*`, by contrast, matches an arbitrary number of arbitrary characters (because `.` in a regex matches any character), and `doi: .*` matches `doi:` followed by a space and then all characters until the end of the line.